# How text files are inputed in C++

Tags: c++, text-files

I am trying to input a text file with data delimited by spaces into my C++ program, but I don't understand how it works. I want to be able to go line by line and if it sees a # symbol it recognizes its a comment and then skips it. I wish to assign the data to variables in my program. I am new to C++, so i was wondering if there was any tips I could get? Thank you so much!

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+line+by+line

Answer (score 3):

Just to give you a taste...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    while (getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        if (!line.empty() && line[0] != '#')
        {
            // do whatever with line (e.g. copy it to another variable)
        }
    }
}
```